# Android: Setting Custom Title/Action Bar - not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I am trying to set a custom Title Bar as follows (please note this activity extends from FragmentActivity if it matters):

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
...
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.window_title, null);    
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titlex);    
        tv.setText("My Title");

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);                

        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
    }
    ...
}
```

But i do not see the Custom Title Bar at all, what is missing?

Comment: Try extending to ActionBarActivity and not Fragment Activity

Comment: Actually actionbaractivity is deprecated; use AppCompatActivity

Comment: On which android version you are running your code?

Comment: Maybe you must be change activity theme on your manifest.

Comment: Eenvicible> Thankyou for the tip about AppCompatActivity - it would be useful if you could post an example usage of that.

Comment: Praveen> I am trying to run on Android KitKat (4.4.4), and i have the following in android manifest>  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: goonerdroid> I do need FragmentActivity becz i am using that for fragments paging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);` before `actionBar.setCustomView(v);`

EDIT

Here i past my code for Custom ActionBar creation

```
// Action Bar Customization
    ActionBar ab =act.getActionBar();

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(act.getResources().getColor(color.ActionBar_bg));
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);


    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // disables default title on
                                            // actionbar.
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // enables custom view.
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // hides app icon.
    ab.setTitle("");
    // Inflating Layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View customActionBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
    txtUserName=(TextView)customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

    ab.setCustomView(customActionBar);
```

Comment: Meenaxi> That seemed to work partially.. the default action bar continues to show, along with my custom title. Seems weird..

Comment: can you please paste some screen shots of your action bar?

Comment: It roughly looks like this: [AppIconHere App_Name    My-Custom-Title-Here], while what is expected is only [        My-Custom-Title-Here                  ]

Comment: Superb!! That worked...included these lines: ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
    ab.setTitle("");